# Is there a way to view the same list/library in subsites without the use of sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, document-library

I'm attempting to make sharepoint a more useful tool at work but I am limited by what tools im allowed to use. I have a library in the main site that I want to be viewed on all of the subsites, I know this is possible but so far only with the use of sharepoint designer. Is there a way I can do this without the use of sharepoint designer? I also cannot use any code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention whether you are using SharePoint 2010 or 2013.

In 2010 the Content Query Web Part is designed to show content from lists or libraries on different sites as long as they are within the same site collection.  Note that you will need the publishing infrastructure feature activated at the site collection level.

In 2013 you still have the CQWP though there are also Content Search Web Parts which will do similar - though these can also work across different site collections.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple page on your main site. Turn off the ribbon and side navigation bar, then use a page viewer in the sub-sites to display it.

Comment: Then it would be easier just to use the View page directly and add `?IsDlg=1`